# How to read EDB file in C++

Tags: c++, windows, edb

I'm writing a program to read edb file in c++
I've tried with esent windows library and I got "The database page size does not match the engine" error on "JetAttachDatabase"

And i also tried "libesedb" library, but i can't understand how to use it.

Is there any other way to read edb in c++ or how can I fix errors

Comment: Please, try [google 'JetAttachDatabase "The database page size does not match the engine"'](https://www.google.com/search?q=JetAttachDatabase+%22The+database+page+size+does+not+match+the+engine%22). It seems that you set wrong page size (or you relied on the default) which doesn't match your edb file. (I must admit that I heart first time about edb in your posting but googled out of curiosity.)

Comment: Thanks Scheff. I googled it but i can't get enough answer. I want more detailed solution or example code